# App crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) on repeated viewcontroller push/pop with async core data fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, exc-bad-access

My app crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error :( It's been giving me a headache for a couple of days now. The crash happens when repeatedly pushing and popping a UIViewController who in turn does asynchronous CoreData fetch. After a 3-4 times it usually happens. The simplified situation looks as follows:

I have a UINavigationController with a UIViewController as rootController. This UIViewController does a push like this:

```
UINavigationController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"List"]; // List is the StoryboardID of another UIViewController.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Next, the pushed UIViewController executes a NSAsynchronousFetchRequest like this:

```
- (void)fetchData
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:self.entityName];
    fetchRequest.predicate = self.basePredicate;

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    // Initialize asynchronous fetch request.
    NSAsynchronousFetchRequest *asynchronousFetchRequest = [[NSAsynchronousFetchRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest completionBlock:^(NSAsynchronousFetchResult *result) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            weakSelf.fetchedItems = [NSSet setWithArray:result.finalResult];
        });
    }];

    // Execute asynchronous fetch request.
    [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
        NSError *asynchronousFetchRequestError = nil;
        [weakSelf.managedObjectContext executeRequest:asynchronousFetchRequest error:&asynchronousFetchRequestError];

        if (asynchronousFetchRequestError) {
            DDLogError(@"Unable to execute asynchronous fetch result: %@, %@", asynchronousFetchRequestError, asynchronousFetchRequestError.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash only happens when setting the results to the fetchedItems var it seems. When removing that line it doesn't happen so I suspect there must be something up with that. I've tested with "Enable Zombie Objects", when I enable this the app does not crash nor does it give me any additional information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a good example of this at the following [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/new-in-core-data-and-iOS-8-asynchronous-fetching/). In looking at it it may have something to do with you using GCD (i.e. the dispatch_async call) instead of using NSPersistentStoreAsynchronousFetchResultCompletionBlock for the completion block as in the example.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't seem to make a difference. However, the article was indeed helpful and led me to finding a (so far) working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link from deanware's comment somehow led me to find a solution. At least so far it seems to be working properly now. I must admit, core data and multi-threading is still a big challenge for me with lots of trial/error. The following solved my problem and I hope to one day fully understand why.

I replaced:

```
_managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;
```

by:

```
_managedObjectContext = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] newChildManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType tracksChanges:YES];
```

(I'm using RestKit, by the way)